# How to check duplicates of the TITLE relevant to and ALT_ID of an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**This is my array. This array is very big one more than 1000 records. 
I wrote some code.**

It will work without duplicates only for `ALT_ID`. `TITLE` will show with the duplicate.

How to check duplicates of the `TITLE` relevant to and `ALT_ID` of an array.

I want to know how to check duplicates of the title relevant to an id of an array.

```
    Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [TITLE] => Business Management   
            [LAST_NAME] => Stu2455
            [ALT_ID] => 2003455
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2492
            [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => Coursework
            [MARKS] => 56.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [TITLE] => Business Management 
            [LAST_NAME] => Stu2455
            [ALT_ID] => 2003455
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2492
            [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => Exam
            [MARKS] => 61.00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [TITLE] => Communication Skills in English
            [LAST_NAME] => Stu2455
            [ALT_ID] => 2003455
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2492
            [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => Exam
            [MARKS] => 45.00
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [TITLE] => Communication Skills in English
            [LAST_NAME] => Stu2455
            [ALT_ID] => 2003455
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2492
            [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => Course Work 
            [MARKS] => 57.00
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [TITLE] => Digital Circuits and PC Hardware 
            [LAST_NAME] => Stu2455
            [ALT_ID] => 2003455
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2492
            [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => Exam
            [MARKS] => 20.00
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [TITLE] => Digital Circuits and PC Hardware 
            [LAST_NAME] => Stu2455
            [ALT_ID] => 2003455
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2492
            [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => Coursework
            [MARKS] => 67.00
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [TITLE] => Elements of Electronics  
            [LAST_NAME] => Stu2455
            [ALT_ID] => 2003455
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2492
            [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => Exam
            [MARKS] => 62.00
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [TITLE] => Elements of Electronics  
            [LAST_NAME] => Stu2455
            [ALT_ID] => 2003455
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2492
            [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => Course Work
            [MARKS] => 79.00
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [TITLE] => Introduction to Databases Systems   
            [LAST_NAME] => Stu2455
            [ALT_ID] => 2003455
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2492
            [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => Coursework
            [MARKS] => 49.00
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [TITLE] => Introduction to Databases Systems  
            [LAST_NAME] => Stu2455
            [ALT_ID] => 2003455
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2492
            [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => Exam
            [MARKS] => 34.00
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [TITLE] => Mathematics for Computing & Business     
            [LAST_NAME] => Stu2455
            [ALT_ID] => 2003455
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2492
            [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => Course Work
            [MARKS] => 82.00
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [TITLE] => Mathematics for Computing & Business    
            [LAST_NAME] => Stu2455
            [ALT_ID] => 2003455
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2492
            [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => Exam
            [MARKS] => 87.00
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [TITLE] => Personal Computer Based Applications   
            [LAST_NAME] => Stu2455
            [ALT_ID] => 2003455
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2492
            [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => Course Work
            [MARKS] => 73.00
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [TITLE] => Visual Basic Programming   
            [LAST_NAME] => Stu2455
            [ALT_ID] => 2003455
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2492
            [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => Exam
            [MARKS] => 56.00
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [TITLE] => Visual Basic Programming   
            [LAST_NAME] => Stu2455
            [ALT_ID] => 2003455
            [STUDENT_ID] => 2492
            [ASSIGNMENT_TITLE] => Coursework
            [MARKS] => 62.00
        )
    )
```

**Below I wrote PHP Code**

```
    $tmp_results = array();
foreach($result as $item => &$rv) {
    if(!isset($tmp_results[$rv['ALT_ID']]))
    {
        $output .= "<tr><td>" . $rv['ALT_ID'] . "</td>";
        $tmp_results[$rv['ALT_ID']] = $rv;                                  
    }

    if(!isset($tmp_results[$rv['TITLE'] || $rv['ALT_ID']]))
    {
        $output .= "<td>". $rv['TITLE'] ."</td><tr>";
        $tmp_results[$rv['TITLE']] = $rv;
    }
}
```

**I want to know how to check duplicates of the title relevant to an id of an array.**

Comment: Just check out my answer

Comment: Check my answer, which must print unique ALT_ID and unique TITLE to an ID

Comment: What's wrong with you, why don't you reply if you have an issue or not?

Comment: @Deshak9 I added your code. unique ALT_ID ok. But, not unique TITLE.

Comment: @sam Edited my answer. please check now.

Comment: Your answer is ok. But, Only first record is duplicated

Comment: @samdiva check out this code https://kopy.io/41tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$tmp_results = array();
foreach($result as $item => &$rv) {

 if(!isset($tmp_results[$rv['ALT_ID']]))
 {
    $output .= "<tr><td>" . $rv['ALT_ID'] . "</td>";
 }

 $currentTitle = $rv['TITLE'];
 $titles = isset($tmp_results[$rv['ALT_ID']]) ? $tmp_results[$rv['ALT_ID']] : array();

 if(array_search($currentTitle, $titles) === false)
 {
     // Write you business logic as Title with respect to your ALT_ID will be unique here.
     $output .= "<td>". $currentTitle ."</td><tr>";

     array_push($titles,$currentTitle);
     $tmp_results[$rv['ALT_ID']] = $titles;
 }
}
```

Comment: I addded this code. but, same happened like I added image. Will showing duplicate `Title`.

Comment: Your answer is ok. But, Only first record is duplicated

Comment: Do you mean "Business Management" is duplicated?

Comment: Also, verify those titles are equals with the case sensitivity.

Comment: Thank you soo much for the answer Deshak9

Comment: Did you figure out, what was wrong with "Business Management"?

Comment: I put only `==`, But It need to be `===`

Comment: How get sum of `MARKS` separately. please can you help me.

Comment: @Sam You want sum of all marks or group them by ALT_ID

Comment: @Deshaj9 I want the sum of the marks according to the title `TITLE`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could overcome this issue. It might help you. You can replace your columns names as you wish

```
$arr = [
'key' => ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'basheer'],
'key3' => ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'salman'],
'key2' => ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'basheer'],
];


$duplicates = [];
$filterd = array_filter($arr, function($v) use (&$duplicates, $arr) {

    //check within duplicate items
    if(in_array($v['id'], $duplicates) && in_array($v['name'], $duplicates)) {

        return false;
    }
    //move on to push duplicate items within array
    array_map( function($v2) use ($v, &$duplicates) { 

        if($v2['id'] === $v['id'] && $v2['name'] == $v['name']) {
            $duplicates[] = $v['id'];
            $duplicates[] = $v['name'];
        }
    }, $arr);


    return $v;
});
var_dump($filterd);
    array(2) {
  ["key"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "basheer"
  }
  ["key3"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "salman"
  }
}
```

Comment: I added this, But, not showing any data. can you help me

Comment: @samdiva what's not showing, paste your array in `php format`.

Comment: @samdiva Can you join this channel. It requires no auth http://tlk.io/stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks you soo much Basheer. for you help.